# Make a website that always keeps its ratios

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to build a website that always keeps its ratios and adapts to user screen size but i can't achieve that.

I've startedd with building a simple fixed width/height frame like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WxNrh/ and started playing around with it but I always get stuck.

What I want to achieve is that the max-width would be 800px and depending on the user screen resolution (or how much I shrink my browser window) the website would shrink accordingly but always keep its width/height ratios.

Here is my fixed website:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">Header</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

And css:

```
#wrapper{width: 800px; height: 400px;}
#header{background-color: red; width: 800px; height: 100px;}
#left{float: left; background-color: yellow; width: 200px; height: 200px;}
#right{float: left; background-color: orange; width: 600px; height: 200px;}
#footer{clear: both; background-color: blue; width: 800px; height: 100px;}
```

I would really appreciate any help! :)

Edit:

I got the desired effect with this css:

```
#wrapper{max-width: 800px;}
#header{background-color: red; width: 100%; padding-top: 12.50%;}
#left{float: left; background-color: yellow; width: 25%; padding-top: 25.00%;}
#right{float: left; background-color: orange; width: 75%; padding-top: 25.00%;}
#footer{clear: both; background-color: blue; width: 100%; padding-top: 12.50%;}
```

But the problem is it works by using padding which forces my div content down which means it's not very usable - due to content not being where it supposed to be.

Comment: Please don't bypass the rules of this website by turning a line of text into code.  Don't you think there was a reason you got an error telling you to post code along with that jsFiddle link?

Comment: Google for "Responsive" web design, there are MANY articles and videos on the subject, and when you have a specific question about that, post back.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WxNrh/1/

Comment: He wants to keep the width/height ratios. That's more than responsive. The trick is padding =) I'll update your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks box86rowh, thats exactly how far i got myself. The problem is i dont know how to make height keep its ratio to width. For example if header width is 800 and height is 100 and i shrink it by half then width will be 400 and i want height to be 50px bur currently it will still stay 100px.

Comment: It implies font-size will shrink to unreadeable sizes, isn't it?

Comment: What you're asking for is in fact what smartphones and tablets - by lack of alternatives on existing websites a few years ago - do since the first iPhone: asssume the width is approx. 960px, render the page as on desktop and let the user zoom in and out and scroll on both axis to have a chance to read anything. This rendering respects the ratio W/H as it's the desktop view...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voila. http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/WxNrh/2/show/

`padding` to the rescue. It's not very useful though, because your content might not fit into the boxes...

The magic is relative padding and absolute positioning:

```
.outer {
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    /* padding-bottom: 25%; in the actual div like #header */
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and a whole load of wrapper divs =( (`.inner` and `.outer`):

```
<div class="outer" id="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="outer" id="header">
            <div class="inner">Header</div>
        </div>
        <div class="outer" id="content">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="outer" id="left">
                    <div class="inner">Left</div>
                </div>
                <div class="outer" id="right">
                    <div class="inner">Right</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="outer" id="footer">
            <div class="inner">Footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There IS one case this is very useful in. Sometimes you really need to keep that aspect ratio: responsive video. For content boxes and entire pages: not so useful.

But you asked!

Comment: +1 Nice, I did [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/552067) on this padding behavior a while back.

Comment: Yup, that's the one. Only useful for responsive video.

Comment: Thanks, i messed around with paddings myself and also found it a bit problematic for content divs and whole website.
But then again there doesent seem to be a better solution for what im looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#wrapper{width: 800px; height: 400px;}
#header{background-color: red; width: 100%; height: 25%;}
#left{float: left; background-color: yellow; width: 25%; height: 25%;}
#right{float: left; background-color: orange; width: 75%; height: 25%;}
#footer{clear: both; background-color: blue; width: 100%; height: 25%;}
```

Using percentages may not work with `float: left;`. See how it goes. It it fails, you can trying using `max-width` and `max-height` or `min-width` and `min-height`.

Comment: I tried this myself too (with max-width and max-height). 
The problem is that i want my height always stay the right ratio with my width. With this code my width changes ok but height always stays the same.

Comment: @user1985273 OK, try just using the percentages then.

Answer (score 1):

### Using an Image to Drive Ratio

I've found the best way to do ratios is often to use an `img` set to the ratio you desire, and have that drive the container size.

**[Here is an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WxNrh/6/)** that modifies your original code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img class="ratioDriver" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff.gif&text=2w:1h+Ratio" />
    <div id="header">Header</div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="left">Left</div>
        <div id="right">Right</div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 800px; 
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.ratioDriver {
   width: 100%;   
   display: block; 
}

#header{
    background-color: red; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 25%; /* 100 / 400 = .25 = 25% */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: yellow; 
    width: 25%; /* 200 / 800 = .25 = 25% */
    height: 50%; /* 200 / 400 = .5 = 50% */
}
#right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    background-color: orange; 
    width: 75%; 
    height: 50%;
}
#footer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 25%;
}
```

### Two ways to deal with the content

You still have to decide how to deal with your content.

**Option 1**

Do you want it [to have separate scroll bars on overflow](http://jsfiddle.net/WxNrh/8/) using `overflow: auto` on your components? This is the best option if content is unknown in size.

**Option 2**

Do you want to try and scale it, which will require a fixed size content for you to work out the factors for. This is really only workable [in modern browsers](http://www.sitepoint.com/new-css3-relative-font-size/) (working well in Firefox 19 and IE9, but Chrome 25 is not functioning correctly as of this writing). This [fiddle roughly achieves it](http://jsfiddle.net/WxNrh/24/) using these additions to the above css with some added content in the html:

```
html {
    font-size: 1vw;
}
 #header{
    font-size: 3rem;
}
#left{
    font-size: .99rem;
}
#right{
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}
#footer{
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```